# Retrieve image one level up of public_html

Tags: php, html

My website allow user to upload photo. The upload code is placed in `public_html/fileupload.php`

The path in the fileupload.php is `../user_upload/abc/`

I saw the folder `user_upload/abc` was created, but my HTML is unable to retrieve the image within. The HTML code is `<img src="../user_upload/abc/myphoto1.jpeg">`

It shows Error 404

Comment: Technicaly your webserver is 'rooted' in public_html and since he's not allowwed to serve anything outside of 'public_html' it will give you 404. You could make a symlink from your upload folder into your public_html and still be able to tell PHP to shove the file in you ABC and read it throug the symlink from let say /public_html/linkToAbc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image folder is outside of the `public_html` directory so it cannot be loaded via a URL. Files outside of public_html are protected from being seen on the web.

Move it inside the `public_html` directory if you wish to have the images displayed inside your website.

Comment: Or make a symlink (if your allowed to follow them)

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier That would defeat the purpose of creating a directory outside of the public_html folder with the expectation that it's protected from web-based attacks. Moving the directory into the public_html folder and setting `php_flag engine off` in the image folder's .htaccess file to disable PHP execution would be a simpler, easier and more structured way to manage this.

Comment: not really , my site doesnt even have a public html

Comment: @Drewby i agree with the security aspect but i often find public_ftp along side the public_html and sometimes you need to allow someone to upload in a rooted deadend and make file accessible elsewhere. Just like you can symlink yor private_html to your public_html to avoid code/file duplication. Symlink exist for a reason and apache can follow then for a reason as well. Depend on how much securty you are willing to sacrifice to do what you have to do. This said, I totally agree with your statement.

Comment: could you elaborate `setting php_flag engine off in the image folder's .htaccess file to disable PHP execution `

Comment: Create a new `.htaccess` file in your image folder's directory, and then add `php_flag engine off` to it and save. You can add additional security by disabling the Apache handler for PHP too with `RemoveHandler .php .phtml .php3`.